# Reading tab-delimited text file into R only expecting one column out of five

Tags: r, readr

Here's my problem. I'm trying to read a tab-delimited text file into R, and I keep getting an error messages and it only loads one column out of the five in the dataset.

Our professor is requiring us to use the read_csv() command for this, but I've tried using read_tsv() as well, and neither has worked. I've looked into it everywhere, I just can't find anything about what could possibly be going wrong.

```r
waste <- read_tsv("wasterunup.txt", col_names=TRUE, na=c("*"))
```

I can't seem to link the text file here, but it's a simple tab-delimited text file with 5 columns, column headers, 22 rows (not counting the headers). * is used for N/A results.

I have no clue how to do this "properly" according to my professor by using read_csv.

```r
waste <- read_tsv("wasterunup.txt", col_names=TRUE, na=c("*"))
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  `PT1      PT2     PT3      PT4     PT5` = col_double()
)
Warning: 22 parsing failures.
row col  expected    actual             file
  1  -- 1 columns 5 columns 'wasterunup.txt'
  2  -- 1 columns 5 columns 'wasterunup.txt'
  3  -- 1 columns 5 columns 'wasterunup.txt'
  4  -- 1 columns 5 columns 'wasterunup.txt'
  5  -- 1 columns 5 columns 'wasterunup.txt'
... ... ......... ......... ................
See problems(...) for more details.
```

To clarify my errors:
When I use read_csv(), all of the data is there, but all five datapoints are crammed into one cell of each row.
When I use read_tsv(), only one column of the data is there.

Comment: This may be a good source to start: ```vignette("readr")```, you may have to specify the column type beforehand.

Comment: What does that mean? The column type is simply just a string.

Comment: found the data here you can add to the question: read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mariarizzo/RbyExample/master/Rx-data/wasterunup.txt"
        )

Comment: `read_tsv` is not seeing the spaces between the column names as tabs.  You can try editing the file and adding tabs or skip the reading the header and rename the columns afterwards.

Comment: Hey, I ended up figuring out it must've been an issue with the file itself. The following code works:
wasterunup <- read_table2("wasterunup.txt")